# Defining configuration for website

Tags: php

I have some doubts about what's the better way of defining configs for my web scripts.
Currently I have something like this:

```
switch($lang){  
    case 'en':
        define('VAR1', 'abc')  
        define('VAR2', 'def')  
        break;
    case 'unk':
        define('VAR1', 'omg')  
        define('VAR2', 'wtf')  
        break;  
}
```

etc. Looks a bit weird to me (wasn't my idea), but it works fine.
My idea, however, was to define an array of these configs:

```
$vars = array(  
    'en'=>array( 
        'VAR1'=>'abc',  
        'VAR2'=>'def'  
    ),
    'unk'=>array(  
        'VAR1'=>'omg',  
        'VAR2'=>'wtf'  
    )  
)
```

How do you think, which one would be better? The `define` way is a bit prettier since I only need to write `<?=VAR1 ?>` instead of `<?=$vars[$lang]['VAR1'] ?>`, but is it wise to use `define` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you should split your translations to different files instead of putting 2 (or more) in same file. What will happen if you have over 1000 lines of translations?

If you want to use the DEFINE and switch anyway, you can try it like:

```
switch ($lang) {
case 'en':
    require_once ('path/to/lang/trans.en.ext');
    break;
case 'unk':
    require_once ('path/to/lang/trans.en.ext');
    break;
default:
    require_once ('path/to/lang/trans.default.ext');
    break;
```

}

And putting your setting in those files. I use same approach in a project of mine, but only for configurations between production, develop and sandbox settings. For localizations I create a class, which works almost in same way as you describe, but using separate  files.

Good luck!

Comment: The things with these translations is that it becomes increasingly difficult (at least for me and now) to understand how is the text parsed, presented and accessed. But I'll try my best to understand it, thanks :)

Comment: If you prefer something used from a lot of ppl, try the [getteext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) and maybe get more info about it here inside [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gettext). Good luck.

Comment: I don't have a preference, I'm just looking for something simple, or at least with good, short and easy to understand documentation/howto. In this case, I have no idea where and what is stored (after parsing) from this and how I can access that data: `require_once ('path/to/lang/trans.default.ext');`

Comment: But you understand what my suggestion does, right? You just put your definitions in those files. My approach will be something like that. Add in master language file:

DEFINE('MY_SLOGAN', 'The is Only One');
DEFINE('MY_HEADLINE', 'Hello to everyone');

than, those same definitions are put in other two files (en and unk for example) and you translate defined part. Do you get that, or I should add you bigger example? :)

Comment: I'm currently working so unfortunately I don't have much time nor free brain power to get into it... I get that there are separate files for each translation and the texts are mapped to common names (MY_SLOGAN etc.), but where do they go and how do I access them after `require_once`? Edit: oh wait, if they're defined then I get it... but then it's just another way to do what I already have.

Comment: Yes, but cleaner. In general, whatever you decide to use, you will need to set your variables/definitions in every files, otherwise it's not possible to pick translations. If you use mysql approach, than you may use one table and many columns (one column per language). If you want, I can give you example of such usage too.

Comment: No, MySQL for that wouldn't be a good idea, It's static data and I wouldn't want to spend MySQL connections just for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably talking about localization. The best way is to use [gettext-related tools](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php).

If you are talking about config, the best way to write it down is to use ini files which PHP can easily parse.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing and reading INI scripts. Most end-users and system administrators are used to the format.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php